# PG - How to drop the type and keep the table

Tags: postgresql

In PG 16, is there a way to avoid the error below when running `DROP TYPE user_state;`?

> Query 1 ERROR at Line 1: : ERROR:  cannot drop type user_state because other objects depend on it
> DETAIL:  column state of table users depends on type user_state
> HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

I need to keep the `users` table.

Comment: How do you suppose the table column of that type would continue to exist without the type definition?

Comment: So what do you wish to happen to the column of the would-be orphaned type?

Comment: Please share type definition also

Answer (score 0):

You could change the type of the column `state` using `user_type` to something different, e. g. text.

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN state TYPE text;
```

If there are not columns left using the type, dropping the type will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a try.